# Perl DBD::SQLite::db do failed: syntax error

Tags: multithreading, sqlite, perl

I am developing a Perl script to query the PasteBin API using threads and DBD::SQLite to store information for later.

Upon running my script I get the following error:

`DBD::SQLite::db do failed: near "day": syntax error at getpaste.pl line 113.`
                                                                                                                                                               `Thread 3 terminated abnormally: DBD::SQLite::db do failed: near "day": syntax error at getpaste.pl line 113.`

Using my code to debug here's what I see in `thread 3`:

```
enum _Days {
  Monday,
  Tuesday,
  Wednesday,
  Thursday,
  Friday,
  Saturday,
  Sunday
}

class HeadingItem implements ListItem {
  String _weekday;
  final int time;
  final DocumentReference reference;

  set day(String weekday) {
    var value = _Days.values[int.parse(weekday) - 1].toString();
    var idx = value.indexOf(".") + 1;
    var result = value.substring(idx, value.length);
    _weekday = result;
  }

  String get day {
    return _weekday;
  }

  HeadingItem.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map, {this.reference})
      : assert(map['day'] != null),
        assert(map['time'] != null),
        day = map['day'], // 'day' isn't a field in the enclosing class  <--- this is the error that im stuck on...
        time = map['time'];

  HeadingItem.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot) : this.fromMap(snapshot.data, reference: snapshot.reference);
}
```

If I had to make an educated guess it bombs out at `String get day {`

Here's a chunk of my code where this is relevant:

```
sub threadCheckKey {
    my ($url, $key) = @_;
    my $fullURL = $url.$key;
    my @flaggedRegex = ();
    my $date = strftime "%D", localtime;
    my @data = ();

    my $thread = threads->create(sub {
        my $dbConnection = openDB();
        open(GET_DATA, "curl -s " . $fullURL . " -k 2>&1 |") or die("$!");
        open(WRITE_FILE, ">", $key . ".txt") or die("$!");
        while(my $line = <GET_DATA>) {
            print WRITE_FILE $line;
            foreach my $regex(@regexs) {
                if($line =~ m/$regex/) {
                    if(!($regex ~~ @flaggedRegex)) {
                        push(@flaggedRegex, $regex);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        close(WRITE_FILE);
        close(GET_DATA);


        open(READ_FILE, $key . ".txt") or die("$!");
        while(my $line = <READ_FILE>) {
            push(@data, $line);
        }
        close(READ_FILE);

        my $updateRow = qq(UPDATE $tables[0] set data = \'@data\', date = \'$date\', regex = \'@flaggedRegex\' where pastekey = \'$key\');
        my $executeRowUpdate = $dbConnection->do($updateRow);

        if($executeRowUpdate < 0) {
            print $DBI::errstr;
        }
```

Line 113 in this case is `my $executeRowUpdate = $dbConnection->do($updateRow);` Knowing Perl it's really complaining about my UPDATE statement just above it.

Where am I going wrong with this? I am a novice when it comes to interacting with anything sql related.

Comment: Why don't you print out $updateRow and see what it is actually trying to execute in the database?

Comment: I see 1) a shell injection bug, 2) an SQL injection bug, 3) use of an experimental feature with a broken design, 4) an `if` condition will never be true (`$executeRowUpdate < 0`), 5) use of 2-arg `open`, 6) O(N^2) code that could be made O(N), 7) needless use of global variables, 8) needless assignments of empty lists to empty arrays, and 9) a `while` loop that can be eliminated by using `<>` in list context. You should have this code [reviewed](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)!

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/206838/pastebin-scraper-based-on-user-regex is the attempt at code review.  Broken code should not be sent there.

Answer (score 1):

You need to log the `$updateRow` that is generated and then look at that and see what is wrong with it.  Without that nobody knows.

The other issues ikegami notes in a comment above probably deserve new questions focused on their individual aspects.  As you've discovered https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is not for code with errors.  But given all of the injection issues it might be time to try https://security.stackexchange.com/

If you fix those problems maybe your error will disappear too.  Or not, but it is worth trying.